# Flash not working in Internet Explorer 7!

Tags: flash, xhtml

Dunno why it's not working correctly. Works fine in Safari, Firefox and IE 8, but I can't get it to work in IE 7. It's a wordpress plugin if that helps.

http://www.laflyfishing.com/video

Thanks guys!

Comment: What Flash version do you have installed in IE7?

Comment: Works in IE8, but not in IE8 compatibility view.

Comment: Try not using IE7 LOL.  Actually, you should probably uninstall any Flash add ons in IE, then go to Adobe.com within IE7 and download it again.  Another option is check your security under Internet Options.

Comment: What Flash version do you have installed in IE7?

Comment: @Josh: You're missing the point. Michael is trying to fix his site, not trying to fix IE.

Comment: Well the thing is I know it's possible to view it in IE 7 because I've used the exact same plugin here: www.cseoutdoors.com and the flash works fine. 

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Thanks for the responses guys! I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to fix it from a developer perspective not an individual user.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the 64 bit version of IE? As far as I know there is no 64 bit version of Flash yet.

Comment: Well the thing is I know the plugin has the potential to work in IE 8 compatibility mode (IE 7) because I'm running the same plugin at cseoutdoors.com with no problems.